# c# - Unity - Erro: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity3d, html-tags, unity-5, 2d

Eu sou iniciante em programação C#, e estou tentando aprender a fazer um jogo sidescroller 2d, mas não consegui avançar de uma parte do tutorial. Isso porque a câmera simplesmente não segue o personagem quando eu aperto o play e o Unity mostra um erro.

Estou seguindo esse vídeo (em inglês), e, ainda que eu escreva do mesmo jeito que o cara do vídeo, o Unity dá esse erro (acontece a cada frame do jogo quando eu testo, por isso mais de 11000 erros):

**Video:** [Clique Aqui](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQEsbOALKhc).

O Erro que o console acusou foi:

[image]

Eu quero fazer com que a câmera siga o personagem do jogo:

[image]

Código do script em c# vinculado à câmera para seguir o personagem (CameraFollow):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Vector2 velocity;

    public float smoothTimeY;
    public float smoothTimeX;

    public GameObject player;

    void Start()
    {

        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //O problema diz ser na linha abaixo desse comentário. Eu tentei inverter o posX com o posY, e o erro deu na linha do posY. Também tentei apertar enter e "cortar em vários pedaços" o que está dentro do float posX, o erro parece ser na própria variável posX/posY.
        float posX = Mathf.SmoothDamp(transform.position.x, player.transform.position.x, ref velocity.x, smoothTimeX);
        float posY = Mathf.SmoothDamp(transform.position.y, player.transform.position.y, ref velocity.y, smoothTimeY);

        transform.position = new Vector3(posX, posY, transform.position.z);

    }
}
```

Eu já excluí o Script e criei outro com o mesmo código;

Verifiquei todas as coisas que estão na aba "Hierarchy" do jogo, nenhum deles têm esse mesmo Script vinculado.

Comment: O GameObject Player está com a tag "Player"?

Comment: Sim, se tag quer dizer o nome dele, ele está

Comment: Não, a tag é [isso](http://image.prntscr.com/image/114e819ae2cf4663887bef0f3b70e077.png)

Comment: Ele não estava, coloquei como Player e agora a câmera segue, valeu, não acredito que fiquei tanto tempo empacado pra ter uma solução tão simples kkkk

Comment: @Kylbert não reparei que já lhe tinham ajudado nos comentários, porei convém sempre escrever em resposta a solução das questões, mesmo que encontre solução, responda depois as suas próprias perguntas, visto que assim poderá ajudar outras pessoas, neste caso já não será necessário, visto que já respondi e acrescentei alguma informação relevante.
Agora basta aceitar a minha resposta e esta questão ficará resolvida.
Espero ter ajudado, tanto no unity como nos conselhos sobre o SOPT.
Cumprimentos!

Comment: Sim, obrigado pelos conselhos e informações. Como pôde ver eu sou novo aqui então eu não sabia muita coisa sobre o funcionamento. Sua resposta foi aceita e marcada  como útil :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para poder resolver está questão terá de verificar se **Hierarchy**, no GameObject **Player** se tem a tag **Player**. Tal como nesta imagem:

[image: Tag Player]

Visto que nesta linha de código defenis-te que teria de ter essa tag, para que o resto acontecesse:

```
player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
```

> **Sugestão:** sempre que quiser fazer algo seguro sem que uma Script tenha de achar um GameObject com uma Tag, aconselho a que meta uma
>   variável do tipo `public GameObject` em que quando adicionar a Script
>   como um componente, arraste da Hierarchy o GameObject que pretende.
>   Assim não precisará de o encontrar visto que definiu quem era esse
>   GameObject.

Caso precises de mais informação sobre **Tags**, aconselho-te estes links da **Documentação do Unity**:

- **[GameObject.tag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-tag.html);**
- **[Manual Tags](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html);**
- **[Unity Learn](http://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/tags);**

Answer (score -1):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

/*Código do script em c# vinculado à câmera para seguir o personagem (CameraFollow):/*


public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float xMargin = 1f;      // Distância no eixo x que o jogador pode mover antes da câmera seguir.
    public float yMargin = 1f;      // Distância no eixo y, o jogador pode mover-se antes da câmera seguir.
    public float xSmooth = 8f;      // Quão suave a câmera alcança seu movimento alvo no eixo x.
    public float ySmooth = 8f;      // Quão suavemente a câmera alcança com o movimento do alvo no eixo y.
    public Vector2 maxXAndY;        // As coordenadas máximas x e y que a câmera pode ter.
    public Vector2 minXAndY;        // As coordenadas mínimas x e y que a câmera pode ter.

    private Transform player;       // Referência à transformação do jogador.


    void Awake ()
    {
        // Configurando a referência.
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    }


    bool CheckXMargin()
    {
        // Retorna verdadeiro se a distância entre a câmera eo jogador no eixo x for maior que a margem x.
        return Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x - player.position.x) > xMargin;
    }


    bool CheckYMargin()
    {
        // Retorna verdadeiro se a distância entre a câmera e o jogador no eixo y for maior que a margem y.
        return Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y - player.position.y) > yMargin;
    }


    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        TrackPlayer();
    }
    
    
    void TrackPlayer ()
    {
        // Por padrão, as coordenadas x e y do alvo da câmera são as coordenadas x e y atuais.
        float targetX = transform.position.x;
        float targetY = transform.position.y;

        // Se o jogador se moveu para além da margem x ...
        if (CheckXMargin())
            // ... a coordenada x do alvo deve ser um Lerp entre a posição x atual da câmera e a posição x atual do jogador.
            targetX = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.x, player.position.x, xSmooth * Time.deltaTime);

        // Se o jogador se moveu para além da margem Y ...
        if (CheckYMargin())
            // ... a coordenada y do alvo deve ser um Lerp entre a posição atual da câmera e a posição atual do jogador.
            targetY = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.y, player.position.y, ySmooth * Time.deltaTime);

        // As coordenadas x e y do alvo não devem ser maiores que o máximo ou menor do que o mínimo.
        targetX = Mathf.Clamp(targetX, minXAndY.x, maxXAndY.x);
        targetY = Mathf.Clamp(targetY, minXAndY.y, maxXAndY.y);

        // Defina a posição da câmera para a posição de destino com o mesmo componente z.
        transform.position = new Vector3(targetX, targetY, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```